# Why does "GROUP BY" take the first row among the grouped rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does GROUP BY take(return) the first row among the grouped rows? 
Is there a built in DESC or ASC ordering?

Comment: Most probably because your `group by` is invalid (standard) SQL but MySQL does not reject this and returns a random (aka "indeterminate") value: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: This question is nowhere near detailed enough. Post examples

Comment: @Skeletor. In practice it may do that, but technically, there is no documented reason why it would.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out that the pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` is giving you confusion. Please read this as well as the article he mentioned. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group,** so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. **Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html